# How to list multiple table results in an unordered list

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to list existing user profiles from the database but only one result is shown whereas there are multiple records.

```
  $SQL_Users = "SELECT DISTINCT first_party_code FROM t_planning";
    
    $RESULT = mysqli_query( $conn, $SQL_Users);

    while($row_Users = mysqli_fetch_array($RESULT)) 
    {
        $data0 = "<ul class='list-unstyled users-list'>";

        $SQL_User_Info = "SELECT title, first_name, middle_name, last_name, profile_image_name FROM t_employees WHERE employee_code = '" .  $row_Users["first_party_code"] . "'";
        $RESULT_Users = mysqli_query( $conn, $SQL_User_Info);

        while($Users = mysqli_fetch_array($RESULT_Users)) 
        {
        $data0.= "<li data-toggle='tooltip' data-popup='tooltip-custom' data-placement='bottom' title='" . $Users["title"] . " " . $Users["first_name"] . " " . $Users["middle_name"] . " " . $Users["last_name"] . "' class='avatar pull-up'>
                
        <img class='media-object rounded-circle' src='../uploads/users_profile_images/" . $Users["profile_image_name"] . "' alt='Avatar' height='30' width='30'>
            
        </li>";
    }
        echo $data0.="</ul>";

        mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: You're using the variable `$RESULT_Users` twice -- probably not what you were intending. I.e., the latter is overwriting the former.

Comment: Renamed one $RESULT_Users but still giving one result

Answer (score 1):

Found where the problem was. I was closing the mysqli_close($conn) prematurely.

```
$SQL_Users = "SELECT DISTINCT first_party_code FROM t_planning";
    
    $RESULT = mysqli_query( $conn, $SQL_Users);

    while($row_Users = mysqli_fetch_array($RESULT)) 
    {
        $data0 = "<ul class='list-unstyled users-list'>";

        $SQL_User_Info = "SELECT title, first_name, middle_name, last_name, profile_image_name FROM t_employees WHERE employee_code = '" .  $row_Users['first_party_code'] . "'";
        $RESULT_Users = mysqli_query( $conn, $SQL_User_Info);

        while($Users = mysqli_fetch_array($RESULT_Users)) 
        {
        $data0.= "<li data-toggle='tooltip' data-popup='tooltip-custom' data-placement='bottom' title='" . $Users["title"] . " " . $Users["first_name"] . " " . $Users["middle_name"] . " " . $Users["last_name"] . "' class='avatar pull-up'>
                
        <img class='media-object rounded-circle' src='../uploads/users_profile_images/" . $Users["profile_image_name"] . "' alt='Avatar' height='30' width='30'>
            
        </li>";
        }
        echo $data0.="</ul>";
                                       
    }   

    mysqli_close($conn);
```